# Heap Sort 2d js integer array

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

Am having issues carrying out sorting on a 2d js array, please help me run this code and help me correct whats wrong.

The sorting algorithms correctly sort data in a single dimensional array but return wrong results with 2 dimensional arrays.

Will be glad if you can help out!

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var values  = new Array(102,2,35,8,8,0);
var rows=3, columns=2, d=0;
var receipts = new Array();
      for(var r=0; r<rows; r++){
        receipts[r] = new Array();
      for(var c=0; c<columns; c++){
        receipts[r][c] = values[d++];
        document.write(receipts[r][c] + ", ");

      }
     }

/*
 SORT RECEIVED DATA
 Using Bubble sort
*/


function bubbleSort(arrayData)
{
  document.write("<h3> Bubble Sort</h3>");
  document.write("At the end of first iteration highest element is sorted <br />");

  //Determine execution time
  var start_time = performance.now();

  //Determine and store the number of elements in array
  var arraySize = arrayData.length; 
  document.write(arraySize);
  //Loop through to sort
  for ( var count = arraySize - 1; count>=0; count--)// outer loop loops (number of elements- 1) times
  {
    for ( var counter = 1; counter <= count; counter++)
    {
     for(var c=0; c<=count; c++ ){
    //Compare elements and swap incase
     //if(arrayData[counter-1] > arrayData[counter])
     if(arrayData[count][c] > arrayData[count][c+1])
     {
      //swap positions
      var temp = arrayData[count][c]; 
      arrayData[count][c] = arrayData[count][c+1];
      arrayData[count][c+1] = temp;
  }
  }
  }

  }
  var c = arrayData.length;
  //diplay sorted list
  document.write("<h5>Sorted array with bubble Sort: </h5>");
  /* for(count=0; count<arraySize; ++count){
    document.write(arrayData[count] + ", "); 
    c++;
  }*/
  //display sorted data
  document.write(arrayData);

  //Calculate execution time
  var end_time = performance.now();
  var execution_time = end_time - start_time;
  document.write("<br><h3>" + c + " Sorted successfully using bubble sort. In "+ execution_time + " milliseconds </h3><hr>"); 
  return arrayData;
}

//pass data to sort to bubble sort function
  bubbleSort(receipts);


/*   

       HEAP SORT ALGORITHM

*/
document.write("<h3> Heap Sort</h3>");
document.write("Divide data into 3 heaps and sorts.<br/>");

function heap_sort(arrayToSort){
var array_size = arrayToSort.length, end = array_size-1;

heapify(arrayToSort, array_size);

while(end > 0){
swap(arrayToSort, end--, 0);
siftDown(arrayToSort, 0, end);
}
return arrayToSort;
}

function heapify(arrayToSort, arraySize){
//create 3 heaps: root and 2 sides
var middle = Math.floor((arraySize-2)/2);
while(middle >= 0){
siftDown(arrayToSort, middle--, arraySize-1);
}
}

function siftDown(arrayToSort,start, end){
var root =  start, child = root*2+1, to_swap = root;
while(child <=end){
if(arrayToSort[to_swap]<arrayToSort[child]){
swap(arrayToSort, to_swap, child);
}
if(child+1 <= end && arrayToSort[to_swap] < arrayToSort[child+1]){
swap(arrayToSort, to_swap, child+1);
}
if(to_swap != root){
  swap(arrayToSort, root, to_swap);
  root = to_swap;
}else{
return;
}
to_swap = root;
child = root*2+1;
}
}


//swap function
function swap(arrayToSort,a,b){
var temp = arrayToSort[a];
arrayToSort[a] = arrayToSort[b];
arrayToSort[b] = temp; 
}
//Execution time
var start_time = performance.now();
//call heap sort function
var heap_sorted_array = heap_sort(receipts.slice());

document.write(heap_sorted_array);
var end_time = performance.now();
var execution_time = end_time - start_time;

document.write("<br><h3>" + heap_sorted_array.length+ " Sorted      successfully using heap sort. In "+ execution_time + " milliseconds </h3><hr>");

</script>
```